# Can WebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream() return null without WebException?

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, resharper

Resharper gives the warning

> Possible 'null' assignment to entity with '[NotNull]' attribute

for the line

> `var strmR = new StreamReader(replyStream);`

in the following code (detailed exception handling removed).

```
        Stream replyStream;
        string reply;

        var query = _serverBaseUrl + queryText;
        var wreq = WebRequest.Create(query);
        wreq.Timeout = _serverTimeoutLimit;
        try
        {
            replyStream = wreq.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            var strmR = new StreamReader(replyStream);
            reply = strmR.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            switch (webex.Status)
            {
              /*throw new exceptions*/
            }
        }
        replyStream.Close();
        return reply;
```

My idea is that I shouldn't need to check *replyStream* for null since a *WebException* (or an unhandled exception) should already have been thrown (which I then handle and throw new custom exception) if any error occurs.

Is it possible for *replyStream* to be null without an *WebException* has been thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replyStream` can not be `null`. If `GetResponse()` was successful, `GetResponseStream` always has a value. If anything goes wrong, a `WebException` is thrown. The [documentation of GetResponse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) says the following

> If a WebException is thrown, use the Response and Status properties of
>   the exception to determine the response from the server.

So you can extend your `catch` clause the handle `webex.Response`, too.

Answer (score 2):

No, not really, but ReSharper does not know that. GetResponseStream() returns a Stream object which possibly can be null like any other functions that return param is a Reference type, but StreamReader specifically states that its input cannot be null.